# Triple nested lists Python

Tags: python, list

I have a block of code that gives me a list that has some triple nested lists within it:

```
my_list = [[['item1','item2']], [['item3', 'item4']]]
```

And I would like to make it:

```
my_list = [['item1','item2'], ['item3', 'item4']]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `my_list = list(map(lambda x :x[0], my_list))`

Comment: I sometimes miss Ruby when I write in Python : `[[['item1','item2']], [['item3', 'item4']]].flatten(1)`. To be fair, it happens in both direction.

Comment: What did you research turn up, and why didn't the solutions in it work for your case?

Comment: What do you expect to a happen in the case where there are multiple items in the outer-most list?

Answer (score 24):

Use a list comprehension to select the single sub-sublist from each sublist:

```
>>> my_list = [item[0] for item in my_list]
[['item1', 'item2'], ['item3', 'item4']]
```

It's also possible to flatten out that level of nesting with `sum`, but it's a performance disaster waiting to happen, since it has quadratic run-time:

```
In [5]: my_list = [[[i, i+1]] for i in range(0, 10000, 2)]

In [6]: %timeit sum(my_list, [])
78.6 ms ± 2.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit [x[0] for x in my_list]
187 µs ± 3.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [8]: 78600/187
Out[8]: 420.32085561497325
```

That's a 420x slowdown for a 5000-length `my_list`, which isn't a very long list at all. It's even worse for longer lists.

Comment: I like the look of this too, but you shouldn't for more than very few elements: https://mathieularose.com/how-not-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python/

Comment: Absolutely, since OP's list have few elements we can use this solution. And also I tried to post alteranative solution

Comment: No point doing timeits for minuscule input, it is almost never indicative of bigO performance.

Comment: The second method removes data if `item` has more than 1 element and raises an error if `item` is empty.

Comment: That's subjective if I refer OP's question, isn't it ?

Comment: We don't know what the _real_ data looks like, all we know is that the OP has "a list that has _some_ triple nested lists within it". So we don't know if all the list items are doubly nested 2-item lists, or only some of them are.

Comment: The `sum` approach is terrible, as it takes quadratic time for no good reason.

Answer (score 14):

do the following:

```
my_list = [j for i in my_list for j in i ]
```

Comment: Could do with one `for loop`: `[i[0] for i in my_list]`

Comment: @srig: The double list comprehension is cleaner IMHO. It also doesn't remove data if `i` has more than 1 element, and doesn't raise an error if `i` is empty.

Comment: @EricDuminil, I also thought the same, but then I went by the OP's input `list` :)

Answer (score 13):

A simple, but efficient way is to flatten your triple nested list with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_list = [[['item1','item2']],[['item3','item4']]]
>>> my_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list))
>>> my_list
[['item1', 'item2'], ['item3', 'item4']]
```

Which has `O(n)`complexity for a list of size `n`.

Answer (score 6):

`my_list = list(map(lambda x :x[0], my_list))`

Answer (score 6):

```
my_list = [[['item1','item2']],[['item3', 'item4']]]
```

One-liner with `list comprehension`

```
my_list = [sub[0] for sub in my_list]
```

You could also change `my_list` in place:

```
my_list = [[['item1','item2']],[['item3', 'item4']]]

for i, sub in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[i] = sub[0]

>>> my_list
[['item1', 'item2'], ['item3', 'item4']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `map` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
map(operator.itemgetter(0), my_list)
```

In Python 3 that returns a generator. If you need a `list` wrap the generator inside a `list(...)` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this if you want a quick fix -

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i]=my_list[i][0]
```

Comment: no semicolons sure but why remove the column though?

Answer (score 0):

python3

```
[[x], [y]] = my_list
print([x , y])

[['item1', 'item2'], ['item3', 'item4']]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix, provided you have similar structure of the nested lists the recursive function below (or something similar for other cases) can handle *any level of nesting*. Did not measure performance but it will be less compared to other solutions. Test well before use. In python 2.7

```
def f(x):
    if hasattr(x[0], '__iter__'):
        return f(x[0])
    else:
        return x

>>> my_list = [[['item1','item2']], [['item3', 'item4']]]
>>> [f(elem) for elem in my_list]
[['item1', 'item2'], ['item3', 'item4']]
>>> my_list = [[[['item1','item2']]], [['item3', 'item4']],[[[['item5', 'item6']]]]]
>>> [f(elem) for elem in my_list]
[['item1', 'item2'], ['item3', 'item4'], ['item5', 'item6']]
```

The hasattr() check will skip strings in python 2. Other tests like iter() may consider strings as iterable